# Как Future[Seq[Option[Long]]] привести к типу Long

Tags: scala, future

Я только начал работу со Scala и ни как не могу в ней разобраться.

def setReg (sid: String, reg: String) = {

```
// Получаю Id из БД
val userId = sidDAO.findUserIdBySid(sid).map(us => us.map(_.userId))

// Вношу изменения по полученному Id
userDAO.updateReg(userId, reg)
```

}

Проблема в том что userId имеет формат Future[Seq[Option[Long]]], а мне нужно передавать Long. Как мне привести к нужному типу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Краткий ответ - приводить не обязательно. Можно сразу передавать.

```
sidDAO.findUserIdBySid(sid).map(us =>
  us.map(u => 
    u.userId.map(id =>
      userDAO.updateReg(id, reg)
    )
  )
)
```

---

Но обычно нам нужно дождаться успешного результата `Future`. Для этого внутренние `Future` нужно вытащить наружу из под слоёв `Seq` и `Option`.

a) Убрать `Option` из коллекции можно с помощью `flatten` либо `flatMap`.

```
val userIds: Seq[Long] = users.map(_.userId).flatten
val userIds: Seq[Long] = users.flatMap(_.userId)
```

б) Пройтись по коллекции и обработать каждую `Future` нам поможет `Future.traverse`.

```
val updates: Future[Seq[Unit]] = 
  Future.traverse(userIds)(userId => siDAO.updateReg(userId, reg))
```

в) Вложенные `Future[Future[Long]]` убираются так же с использованием `flatten` или `flatMap`.

Смотрим всё вместе:

```
sidDAO.findUserIdBySid(sid).flatMap{us =>
  val userIds = us.flatMap(_.userId)

  Future.traverse(userIds)(userId => siDAO.updateReg(userId, reg))
}
```

Тоже самое с использованием `for` синтаксиса:

```
for {
  us <- siDAO.findUserIdBySid(sid)

  userIds = us.flatMap(_.userId)

  _ <- Future.traverse(userIds)(userId => siDAO.updateReg(userId, reg))
} yield ()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Использовал твой самый первый пример кода и больше не ругается, но компилироваться не хочет( В routes прописал путь к данной апишке, но получаю:
Compilation error[Cannot use a method returning scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Option[util.db.SlickPgDriver.ProfileAction[Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write]]]] as a Handler for requests]
Можешь подсказать в чем дело? Чет не гуглится(

Comment: Видимо `updateReg` возвращет `ProfileAction`. Почитай в документации к библиотеке как с ней работать. Я с ней не знаком. Предположу, у слика ленивое выполнение и должен быть метод что-то типо `run()` позволяющий `ProfileAction` превратить в значение. Как `Option[Option]` схлопывать я писал выше (flatMap).